# Create variables from text file

Tags: c#, settings

I want to store variables in a `.txt` file - like I always see in peoples `config.txt` files, where it's like:

```
var_name = ['"test url"']
```

I've got the code below that opens the file and reads it (at the moment just debugging and displays what's in the file, at the moment just 1 variable)

```
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\conf\\config.txt");
string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

myFile.Close();

MessageBox.Show(myString);
```

What's in the file is

```
file_name="C:\\test.txt"
```

Now I'd like to be able to use that variable in my functions in my VB form. How do I go about doing this? And also, how can I do multiple; so I can have basically a big list of vars that the form loads at launch?

So for example:

```
// Opens file and reads all variables
// Saves all variables to form
// Can now use varaible in form, e.g. messageBox.Show(file_name);
```

I'm new to C#, I imagine it's similar to an include but the include is local instead of part of the project.

Comment: Why aren't you using `Settings`? Do you really need your own configuration file? Also, files are not C# literals - you should not escape the `\` as `\\` - that would give you `"\\\\"` instead of `"\\"`.

Comment: When you really want to automate this then you're looking at (De-)Serialization, too broad for an answer here. Do look at Settings (under Project, Properties)

Comment: What are `Settings`? Is that basically what I want instead of the trouble I'm going through? I'm using \\ because I only want 1 \ otherwise it's escaped. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Here to learn!

Comment: I should add, if it wasn't clear. I want these variables not to be saved locally in the project (or I'd just set the variables statically the usual way). Instead I'd like them in a file so I can store that on a network drive so it changes all the programs every time I update the config.txt. If that makes sense?

Comment: The format you are showing looks exactly like an old-fashioned `ini` file, except for the section header, e.g. `[settings]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclamer: *standard practice* (i.e. `Settings`) usually is the *best policy*, however the question has been asked and can be asnwered:

I suggest using *dictionary*, e.g.

```
  Dictionary<String, String> MySettings = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\conf\config.txt")
    .ToDictionary(line => line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf('=')).Trim(),
                  line => line.Substring(line.IndexOf('=') + 1).Trim().Trim('"'));

  ...

  String testUrl = MySettings[var_name];
```

However, if you prefer "variables" you can try `ExpandoObject`:

```
  dynamic ExpSettings = new ExpandoObject();

  var expandoDic = (IDictionary<string, object>) ExpSettings;

  foreach (var pair in MySettings)
    expandoDic.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

  ...

  String testUrl = ExpSettings.var_name;
```

Comment: I think I get what you've done here.. One little thing I'm stuck on is how I'm accessing the name MySettings.

And then in a different function:

`private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String test = MySettings[file_name];
            MessageBox.Show(test);
        }`

But it obviously comes up saying it cant find the MySettings

Comment: @Vaughan Slater: implment `MySettings` as a *field* (probably *static field*) fill it in *constructor* (*static constructor*, *first access*)

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way, I'm not sure what a static constructor is; I've only done PHP in the past (dont think I've ever used them). Looking at google it looks like just declaring it before using it. VS doesn't seem to like that. Do I have to make a class for main part of the code with a constructor set, and then I can call MySettings[whatever] anywhere in the form?

Comment: Add a field to the (main) form: `private Dictionary<String, String> MySettings = File ...` and use syntax `MySettings[var_name];` whenever you want in the form

Comment: I know I must be stupid! I've just linked an image, easy for you to see: http://uploadir.com/u/29gmam3z

I think I've done everything right, although it's still saying it can't find MySettings. What do you mean by 'add a field' to the main form? Haven't I done that with Dictionary bit of code?

Comment: @Vaughan Slater: `String test = MySettings["file_name"];` pay attention to *quotation marks*

Comment: Aaaah! Works perfectly now. Thank you so much. :) learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I store and load data (or variables) with Json Deserialization/ serialization in c#.

Here is Serialiazation: I make an object (postlist which is an object list) that i want to save in a text file That way:

```
 private void save_file()
    {
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\list.txt";
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postlist);
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

You need to install Newtonsoft.Json: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json
.You can do it with the Nuget tool console.
Don"t forget to use:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Here is a way to get all your data from the text file, this is the deserialization:

```
private void read_file_list()
    {
        string line;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("list.txt"))
            {
                line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
            postlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(line, jsonSerializerSettings);
        }
        catch 
        {
           // catch your exception if you want
        }
    }
```

And here is how i store all my text in my object list "postlist".

Newtonsoft is very usefull and easy to use, i mostly use it to get data from api's.

This my first answer I hope it will help you.